# Calling ioctl on same file descriptor from two different processes

Tags: linux, kernel, locking, multithreading, ioctl

If I call ioctl (this is a custom kernel driver to read/write Altera registers), and another process calls ioctl on the same file descriptor while the first ioctl is still executing, does the first call finish before the second call starts?

I am unsure if I should put some sort of locking mechanism in the driver, or if it's unnecessary.

Comment: You need to implement locking in driver.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no serialization in the system call interface. If you need to serialize requests, you need to do it yourself in your driver.